# H acting on G by left translation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and acts on $G$ by left translation, describe the orbits. 
Here is my take, at first I thought well, isn't that just left cosets? But, that seems too easy. By translations, does that mean by adding some element of $H$ on the left of $G$? Am I even close to the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got the right idea. The action of left translation means for $h\in H$, the action $*$ is $h*g := hg$, where $g$ ranges in $G$.

The orbits aren't quite the left cosets of $H$. The orbit of $g\in G$ is defined to be
$$\{h*g: h\in H\}.$$
What is this set?

Comment: Quite right (coset, I mean).

Comment: Left cosets of G?

Comment: @cakey No...don't just guess, write out explcitly what this set is.

Comment: So, this is a defintion of a left coset in the regular sense: gH = {gh : h an element of H } and this is a right coset: Hg = {hg : h an element of H }. So I would say it's a right coset then. I'm not sure how to write out something like this in abstract terms.

Comment: That's right, now replace $h*g$ with its definition in my answer and see what you get.

Comment: I'm not quite following.Let's see {h*g: heH}=Hg and I'd describe the orbits to be right cosets. I am unsure of what I am missing, I suppose I thought that was the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! I was just responding to how you said you weren't sure how to write this up rigorously. (At least that's what I interpreted it as.)

Comment: Okay, thanks, but you were right. I should have written down what i was asked to see the right coset.